# How to create voice chat in web browser with java

Tags: java, applet, browser, voice

I want to create a voice chat which runs on the web browser.
The basic idea is that when I run the server.jar file, it will listen to a socket for connection, and when I type the ip and port on another computer on web browser(ex. 1.1.1.1:8082), the server will accept the connection and display an voice chat applet. Server.jar should contain all voice handlers. For example, if we have three computers, one with the server running while other two has web browser applet running and connected to the server, user1 talking will transmit over to the server, which then transmit over to user2.

So far, I have the applet and the server, but I am having trouble using the web browser to open the applet. It seems I need to use servlet and apache tomcat for the server side to make this work.

Can anyone confirm that I need to use servlet and apache tomcat to achieve this? Or can anyone suggest a better way to approach this project?

Answer (score 1):

if it's peer-to-peer, everything can be written inside the applet.

Oh and as far as i know, there is no java voip libraries so you're going to have to port one from a C/C++ library or write it yourself.